# Resources exceeded during query execution - LIKE/Contains with array

Tags: google-bigquery

SELECT foo, GROUP_CONCAT (user_id) as userids
FROM table1
GROUP BY foo 
HAVING userids like foo
--HAVING userids contains foo

For each foo, it may associated to multiple userids. What I would like is to group all of the userids into arrays with foo.

I want to only show the ones where the userid array contains one userid that also matches foo, which is why I add the HAVING clause. I tried like and contains, both gave me the error in the title. What other options do I have?

I tried the same query without the HAVING clause and it failed as well! So looks like GROUP_CONCAT is the issue here.

This is what I want to show.

abc, (abc,dfgdf,46456)

Comment: Update, looking at the data, ( I did a count(*) group by ) and saw that there were millions of null values for foo, so it was probably trying to jam a million items into an array and failed)

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT
  foo,
  GROUP_CONCAT(UNIQUE(user_id)) AS userids
FROM AS table1
GROUP BY foo
HAVING userids CONTAINS foo
```

if still issue, try

```
SELECT
  foo,
  GROUP_CONCAT(UNIQUE(user_id)) AS userids
FROM table1
WHERE foo IN (
  SELECT foo
  FROM table1
  WHERE foo = user_id
)
GROUP BY foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a WHERE foo is not null, apparently  it timedout when trying to jam a million records into one string with GROUP_CONCAT